# IOS push decrement badge on push open in urbanairship push

Tags: ios, cordova, urbanairship.com

I am working on cordova project and using urbanairship for push notificaiton.

Now i need to manage "Badge" for all devices, needs to maintain and incriment badge count on notification arrived and decrement on notificatino open.

For that,I took fork of [Urbanairship plugin](https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push) and change some code for support badge on android and update new plugin [with badge support](https://github.com/naitikpatel1990/phonegap-ua-push-badge) working fine with android.

In IOS badge count is manage it self, just need to send badge count from console.

**Problem:**  I have issue in IOS badge decrement one. On push arrived badge is increment every time. Suppose, i have 5 notification pending in notification list and badge count is 5 now, when i opened one of any notification from 5 that time badge count become 0 and removed and other 4 notification also flush out.

Please advice me to maintain badgcount on open notification on ios for urbanairship.

FYI: 
cordova 6.3.0,
urbanairship plugin (6.0.0 latest),
cordova-ios: 4.2.1

Screen Shots:

1) Five notification in list

[image]

2) Badge for 5 notification

[image]

3) Notification gone and badge after open any of notification list, open any notification and remaining notifications are also flush out and badge also gone:

[image]

Comment: In your _Urbanairship plugin_, do you use `[[UAPush shared] setAutoBadgeEnabled: YES];`? You should have a look in `UAirshipPlugin.m`. Do a quick search with the keyword _badge_ to understand how it works.

Comment: i found one thing in UAirshipPlugin.m of function receivedForegroundNotification: set badge value like [[UAirship push] setBadgeNumber:0]; but when i removed it also no change

Comment: `receivedForegroundNotification` is called when your app is on the top ("displayed") and receive a notification. Just to be sure, when do you want to decrement your badge? When your app is active, or in background?

Comment: i want decrement badge on each click of notification list. wether app is in background of foreground. Need to decrement on notification opened. if only one notification pending need to remove badge instead of making 0.

Comment: Ok, but where is your notification list? On a webpage? Can you add a screenshot, please?

Comment: added screenshots for your understanding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123928/discussion-between-b-7-and-naitik).

Comment: Are you using the following in your config.xml?
`<!-- Clear the iOS badge on launch -->
<preference name="com.urbanairship.clear_badge_onlaunch" value="true | false" />` If set to true, it will set the badge count to zero on launch which also clears all pending notifications in the notification list.

Comment: @gatlinhebert : yes i tested that but, i don't want to remove badge, i want to decrease when user open, also if i open any notification it will flush all other notificaiton.